# How can I disable the excerpt_link in octopress?

Tags: jekyll, octopress

I wrote my posts and added `<!-- more -->` to where I want to stop the content from showing. After this, octopress shows a "read on" link, I want this not to show. I think this snippet (inside `_includes/article.html` file) is the key:

```
{% if excerpted == 'true' %}
    <footer>
      <a rel="full-article" href="{{ root_url }}{{ post.url }}">{{ site.excerpt_link }}</a>
    </footer>
  {% endif %}
```

I tried to delete this snippet and the link still shows. Tried to delete `excerpt_link` from `_config.ylm' and the html is still generated for the link.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do it. Be sure to do it in `sources/_includes/article.html` and not within  `.themes/themeName`.

Comment: Yes that's what I have been doing

Comment: Did you have sources on github ?

Comment: I can get this work with a fresh octopress. Did you try to refresh browser cache ?

Comment: Yes I did. I even loaded the site in a different browser and the result is the same